# Convert multidimensional dictionary (fetchall-type) to multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have the necessity to convert a multidimensional dictionary (as a database fetchall function returns) to a multidimensional list:

*Multidimensional dictionary (fetchall-type)*

```
multi_dict = [
  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
  {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value20', 'key3': 'value30'}
]
```

**Multidimensional list (output wanted)**

```
multi_list = [
  ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
  ['value10', 'value20', 'value30']
]
```

Comment: [entry.values() for entry in multi_dict.items()] or simply iterate over your multi_dict and add the values of your list to your multi_list if i get your question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extract **values** from each dictionary in loop (in this example I used **list comprehension**).

`multi_list = [list(d.values()) for d in multi_dict]`

`list(d.values())` is there because in python3, `.values()` returns `dict_values` object, not `list` so in python2 this can be omited and you can just do `multi_list = [d.values() for d in multi_dict]`.